# Arrays vs Dynamic Arrays

Tags: array, complexity

In *Steven Skiena's The algorithm design manual Edition 2*, he talks about dynamic arrays on *page 67*, which results in them having same Big-Oh as normal arrays. I don't understand how. This is what book states

> Half the elements [in final array] were moved once, a quarter twice, and so on, so total movements M is given by

[image]

Isn't this counting some movements twice?

[image]

(The red part is copied from last array and blue is new inserted part)

For `n` insertions there are `lg n` array reallocations. So 1st item is copied `lg n` times, second one `lg n - 1` times, next 2 `lg n  - 2` times, next 4 `lg n  - 3` times and so on.

[image]

I don't know how to solve this but what am I thinking wrong?

---

Here's my latex code, if someone wants edit it [here](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php)

```
M = 1 \cdot lg_2 n + 1 \cdot (lg_2 n - 1) + 2 \cdot (lg_2 n - 2) + 4 \cdot (lg_2 n - 3)  
= \sum_{i = 1}^{lg_2 n - 1} 2^i \cdot (lg_2 n - i)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's imagine that I insert the first sixteen natural numbers:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
```

The sequence goes like this:

```
1 
1 2
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
```

- The numbers 9-16 are copied once.
- The numbers 5-8 are copies twice.
- The numbers 3-4 are copies three times.
- The number 2 is copies four times.
- The number 1 is copies five times.

> Isn't this counting some movements twice?

No, the half and the quarter in the quote are distinct the values. The quarter isn't part of the half.

Comment: I get it now, I guess I just got confused with the language and thought "half are copied once" is referring to numbers 1-8 in last line. Thanks Winston :)

Answer (score 1):

**Dynamic arrays do not reallocate their size every time you do an insertion.**

Rather, an insertion that requires the size of the array to increase will typically cause the array to *double in size.*  The resulting cost of expansion is *amortized over all of the insertions,*  which is to say that the cost is taken *once* over a geometrically increasing number of insertions, and *not taken again for the original insertions.*

**Further Reading**
[Geometric Expansion and Amortized Cost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array#Geometric_expansion_and_amortized_cost)

Comment: I think the Op realizes that only log n copies happen.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: The amortization is the key concept here, and the fact that the expansion does not occur for every insertion.

Comment: I understand that it only reallocates when size is more than capacity, thus `lg n`. Book states `If half the elements move once, quarter move twice and so on`, say the half is red part of last line in the image, which is moved once from above, and quarter twice, which is copied from 3rd last line to 2nd last and then last line, isn't this counting movement of quarter items 3 times, once when we say half are copied and twice when quarter is copied, but in reality it moved only twice in total?

Comment: I don't think that's relevant.  You take the amortized cost for the next `n` insertions each time you double the size of the array to `2n`.   How many times the items were *previously* moved is irrelevant.

Comment: @Sourabh, When it say that half of the element move once and a quarter move twice, the quarter isn't contained in the half. The quarter is in addition to the half. So overall, that accounts for three quarters of all the elements.